# $f$ surjective iff for every $g:B \rightarrow C, h:B \rightarrow C$ exist $g \circ f=h \circ f \implies g=h.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$ f: A \rightarrow B.$

**Prove / Disprove:**

1. $f$ surjective iff for every $g:B \rightarrow C, h:B \rightarrow C$ exist $g \circ f=h \circ f \implies g=h.$

My solution :

**One direct:**

$f \space surjective \implies \forall \space b\in B \space \exists \space a\in  A \space 
   f(a)=b.$

Suppose $g \neq h$ so $\exists \space b \in B$ so $g(b)\neq h(b) $.

Lets take $a \in A$ that $f(a)=b.$

$(g \circ f)(a)=g(f(a))= g(b) \neq h(b) = h(f(a)) =  (h \circ f)(a)$

Contradiction to $g \circ f=h \circ f. $

**Second direct:**

$g \circ f=h \circ f \implies g=h \implies  $

Suppose $f$ is not surjective so $\exists b\in B$ that $\forall \space a \space f(a) \neq b. $

And the condition of $g \circ f=h \circ f \implies g=h  $ doesnt exist for every $g,h : B 
   \rightarrow C$ , because $(g \circ f)(a)$ and $(h \circ f)(a)$ dont defined

I am not sure about the second direct.

Is my proof correct ?

Comment: You are right in general. You should construct $g,h:B\rightarrow C$ s.t. $g\ne h$ and $g\circ f=h\circ f.$

Comment: The first direction is right. The second one doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Can you help me with the second one please ?

Comment: Let $C=\{c,d\}$ and let $g$ send every $b\in B$ to $c$. Let $h$ do the same except that it sends elements that are not in the image of $f$ to $d$.

Comment: @drhab And this is the proof that f must be surjective ?

Comment: Yes. In contrapositive form. If $f$ is not surjective then the constructed $g,h$ satisfy $g\neq h$ and $g\circ f=h\circ f$ (as suggested by @MaximNikitin).